# Prettier Typescript configuration for keeping the object in one line but its type definition in separate lines

Tags: javascript, typescript, prettier, prettier-eslint

I have code with functions of this format:

```
export const loginService = async ({ email, password }: { email: string; password: string }) => {}
```

I want all these functions to be formatted in this manner:

```
export const loginService = async ({ email, password }: { 
   email: string;
   password: string 
}): Promise<ApiResponse> => {}
```

So that the input object remains in one line but its type definition gets separated into separate lines, like how an interface is divided.
Is there a way to configure this using prettier?

Comment: No, there isn't. Prettier is pretty opinionated. If you don't like how it formats code, don't use it. Better yet, create your own!

Comment: @vr. yeah, creating one seems like the only solution here lol